# New Haans-G monitor show a flickering black screen

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hardware-failure

I bought a [Haans-G HZ201](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824254055) monitor last week at Newegg during their Black Friday sales. It just came on Friday and my parents suggested that I test it out on my laptop to see if there's anything abnormal.

Things I saw/heard/tried:

- After the screen turns off for idling more than 20 mins, chances are that it'll show nothing but a black flickering screen. I have to set the resolution to something lower like 1024 x 768 or 800 x 600 and then set it back up to 1600 x 900 for it to work again
- There's a slight buzzing sound coming out of it (It's not from the built in speakers)
- Auto adjusting the monitor doesn't work

Laptop specs (HDX16-1155CA):

- Intel P7450 2.13 GHz
- 4 GB DDR2 RAM
- Dedicated 9600M GT 512 MB
- The desktop is extended to both monitors
- The monitor is connected via VGA port

Comment: Yes the port works well. I tried my parents' old Benq and it works very well too, and it doesn't make any sort of buzzing sounds either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [one egg reviews](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=24-254-055&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&Pagesize=10&PurchaseMark=&SelectedRating=1&VideoOnlyMark=False&VendorMark=&IsFeedbackTab=true&Keywords=%28keywords%29&Page=1#scrollFullInfo).  Sounds like you've got a lemon.  Newegg will take care of you since it's only been a week, get that RMA opened.